# Map service appears in the web REST view but not in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, rest, web-service

I have an ArcSDE server serving some poly layers through a map service running on ArcGIS Server 10.0.  The service appears to be working--I can navigate to it just fine in the REST view and I can see the data when I do the *View In ArcGIS JavaScript* option.

However when I load up ArcMap and attempt to add the service to a layer it appears to succeed but does not show up; the screen remains white no matter what extent I'm viewing.  The layer is set to be viewable at all extents and appears to be the correct spatial reference so I'm a bit confused why the javascript viewer can see it but not ArcMap.

*edit* I should add that I have a Silverlight app pointing at the service as well and that also does not show the data.

Comment: What happens if you view _just_ the service as a layer (i.e. load it without first loading other layers)? Also, what happens if you Zoom to Layer on that layer?

Comment: Zoom to layer doesn't change anything.  I have the service loaded as the only layer right now and it's still blank.  Full extent also gives me nothing.

Comment: Can you search for an attribute value that you know exists to see if ArcMap can find it (I'm just trying to see if the layer is actually getting loaded and is just not displaying for some odd reason).

Comment: I can see the attribute values but it's not displaying the visuals still.

Comment: So the layer is getting loaded but it's not displaying correctly. (I wish ArcMap had better troubleshooting options.) The only things I can think of checking are to look at the layer properties and make sure that "Show layer at all scales" is checked in General, that the Min and Max Scales appear correct on the Layers tab, and that Layer Transparency is set to 0% on the Advanced tab. You could check the symbology as well to ensure that everything is set up as it should be (though I imagine you've already done that). Good luck.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind providing a URL (and if the service is available outside your network), I can try to take a look at it here.

Comment: What happens if you have ONLY that layer in your map document (e.g. deleting all of the other layers)?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the trouble gents, turns out it was a problem with our ArcGIS Server install.  During the post-install the port was configured to 80 but we later configured the web interface to port 90.  I'm not terribly sure what made it work in the JavaScript viewer but after re-running the post install it works great now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the ArcGIS server port set up.  Make sure you set the ArcGIS server port in the post-install to the correct port or it will fail to load imagery in some circumstances.